# How to move/drag multiple headers in a JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I need to treat multiple columns as a group, by which I mean, the elements of the group should not be reorderable while dragging the group as a whole should be possible. Best would be the same dnd animation JTable does for single columns, just for multiple ones.

Is there a way to achieve this with a JTable/JXTable?

Thanks

Comment: `JTable` supports multiple row selection, but not multiple column selection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the answer, see trashgod's comment above.